# How to get SetBinding method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I need to do something like this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/982e2fcf-780f-4f1c-9730-cedcd4e24320/

I decided to follow the best way as John Smith advised.

I tried to set binding in xaml, it didn't work (target was always null).

I decide to set binding manually in code (for debugging purpose), so I need to execute "SetBinding" method of the DateRange object.

This method doesn't exists in object of type DateRange.

Any ideas?

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Name="Xml_Name"
         >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding XPath="@name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:UniqueValidationRule x:Name="uniqueDatasourcesRule001" >
                    <local:UniqueValidationRule.UniqueCollection>
                        <local:UniqueDependencyObject uu="{Binding  ElementName=Xml_Name, Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </local:UniqueValidationRule.UniqueCollection>
                </local:UniqueValidationRule>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>



public class UniqueDependencyObject : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty uu11Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("uu", typeof(string), typeof(UniqueDependencyObject));

    public string uu
    {
        set { 
            SetValue(uu11Property, value); }
        get { 
            return (string)GetValue(uu11Property); }
    }



}

public class UniqueValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public UniqueDependencyObject UniqueCollection
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        // I set breakpoint to this line and check UniqueCollection.uu - it is always null
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

//  And binding in code:

```
                Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.ElementName = "Xml_Name";
            binding.Path = new System.Windows.PropertyPath("Name");
            binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;


            UniqueValidationRule uVal = new UniqueValidationRule();
            uVal.UniqueCollection = new UniqueDependencyObject();

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(uVal.UniqueCollection, UniqueDependencyObject.uu11Property, binding);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't read all the details of the forum post you're referring to, but i'm sure you need to know a few things about data binding before you can start using it.

1. The target of a data binding is a [dependency
   property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx)
2. A dependency property has to be declared in a class that is derived from [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.DependencyObject.aspx) (at least when it is not an attached property, but we don't talk about those here)
3. The [SetBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx) method you're looking for is either a static method in [BindingOperations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613480), or a method of [FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setbinding.aspx).

So when you're going to set up a binding on some property of your DataRange class, it would have to be derived from DependencyObject, and you would set the binding like this:

```
DataRange dataRange = ...
Binding binding = ...
BindingOperations.SetBinding(dataRange, DataRange.StartProperty, binding);
```

If DataRange were derived from FrameworkElement, you could write this:

```
dataRange.SetBinding(DataRange.StartProperty, binding);
```

Here DataRange.StartProperty is of type [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx) and represents the `Start` dependency property of class DataRange.

You should at least read the MSDN articles [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347), [Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) and [Custom Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx).

Comment: I've done all these steps, but binding still doesn't work.
Thanks for attempt to help.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm having trouble to understand what you're going to do there. Two things to note however. First, there is a naming convention for dependency properties. If the property is named `uu`, the DP must be named `uuProperty`, though that's certainly not the source of trouble here. Second you say that you check `UniqueCollection.uu` and it's always null. Shouldn't that be something like `UniqueCollection[0].uu` or so?

Comment: I wrote that code in a hurry, so it is non readable.
I will try to prepare more understandable example to show the problem later.
I understand what about you speak - that is not the source of the trouble.